# Where does `conda` keep the installed packages on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I installed `python-graphviz` using `conda install python-graphviz` on my Windows 10 machine. But the system complains about

> graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

So I want find the graphviz executable and add it to my path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conda packages are kept in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs`. Specifically, I found my version of graphviz in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.38-hfd603c8_2`.

In order to determine where files are located, I can recommend [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/). The tool which was searched is `dot.exe`. If you have GraphViz installed, it'll be in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Graphviz2.38\bin\`.

Indeed, Conda will install another one in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.38-hfd603c8_2\Library\bin\graphviz\`